# Git user authorization per branch by hook

Tags: git, bash, repository, authorization, githooks

5 developers have access to git-repository through same ssh-account.
I need to limit push-access for some branches (*production, development*) of that repo.
How to implement simple branch security with git hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me point you that in GIT, it is possible to upload more branch with one push command, which, in such case, could be a security risk. To avoid it, you should use a script like the following one (just think that everyone can push to the 1st branch but the 2nd... Authorization will be done for the 1st one - but the 2nd?)

```
while read anotherOldrev anotherNewrev anotherRefname
    do
        newRefType="$(echo $anotherRefname | awk '{split($0,a,"/"); print a[2]}')"
        if test "$newRefType" = "heads"
        then
            #branch
            if test "$refname"
            then
                #branch, 2nd time, which means another branch
            else
                #branch, 1st time
                oldrev=$anotherOldrev
                newrev=$anotherNewrev
                refname=$anotherRefname
            fi
        else
            #tag
        fi
    done
```

In second hand, I'm not sure if you can do authorization in pre-receive hook, since all information you got there are the old reference, new reference and it's name...
...but to change the name temporarily is just a command or two (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! You right about multiple branches in one push. But we practice one brunch push (push.default=current). And there is no requirements about pushing multiple branches. I just need to prohibit whole push if user can't pass authorization.

Comment: I had modified answer to inform user which exactly branch is restricted.

Comment: Minor efficiency hack: use `case`, e.g., `case $ref in refs/heads/*) shortref=${longref#refs/heads/}; reftype=branch;; ...`

Comment: Btw, I recommend you to write it in perl, since it supports git hooks. For more, check eg. http://search.cpan.org/~gnustavo/Git-Hooks-0.046/lib/Git/Hooks.pm

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a pre-receive or update hook, yes.  (The difference here will be that the pre-receive hook can only accept or reject the *entire* push, while the update hook can accept or reject each individual ref-update.)  Note that gitolite supports this "out of the box".  See [the git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-8.html) for a high level overview.

Comment: Gitolite - nice solution, but it use ssh accounts for authorization.

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk : Authorization is different from access control, which is what gitolite uses ssh keys for. If each developer is assigned a different key (a policy one should enforce anyway), gitolite can do its magic. The figure on gitolite's documentation page on how to add/remove users gives a pretty good picture: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#users

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution by **pre-receive** hook:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read old_rev new_rev ref_name; do
    for script in `find $PWD/hooks/pre-receive.d/ -perm -100 -type f`; do
        ${script} "$old_rev" "$new_rev" "$ref_name"
        if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
            status=1
        fi
    done
done

exit ${status}
```

This is file must be in **pre-receive.d** directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

old_rev=$1
new_rev=$2
ref_name=$3

# Secure branches
sec_branches=(refs/heads/production refs/heads/development)

# Authorized users
authorized_users=('John Doe' 'Bob Smith')

# get rev type
zero="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
if [ "$new_rev" = "$zero" ]; then
    new_rev_type=delete
else
    new_rev_type=$(git cat-file -t ${new_rev})
fi

case "$ref_name","$new_rev_type" in
    refs/heads/*,commit)
        # new commit        
        case ${sec_branches[@]} in
            *${ref_name}*)
                # Save committer and author into variables
                commit_prefs=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an:%cn' ${new_rev})
                IFS=":" read author committer <<< "$commit_prefs"

                # if committer and author not in allowed persons - exit
                case ${authorized_users[@]} in
                    *${author}*)
                    ;;
                    *)
                        branch_name=`echo ${ref_name:11}`
                        echo
                        echo "You're not allowed to push in $branch_name branch" >&2
                        echo
                        exit 1
                    ;;
                esac

                # if committer and author not equal - exit
                if [ "$author" != "$committer" ]; then
                    echo
                    echo "You're not author of pushed commits. This is prohibited" >&2
                    echo
                    exit 1
                fi
            ;;
        esac
    ;;
esac
```

**Update**
As noted in comments [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek), this is not secure solution, but it'll prevent accidents.

Comment: That's an update hook (revs and refnames provided as arguments) rather than a pre-receive hook.  (I'd probably use the update hook here, since I think the idea is to just keep certain branches mostly-frozen but allow others to update.)  Note that testing the author and committer is not secure: it's trivial to spoof author (put GIT_AUTHOR in environment) and possible to spoof committer (if you control your own machine :-) ).

Comment: @torek pre-receive hook <old_rev> <new_rev> <ref_name>;
update hook <ref_name> <old_rev> <new_rev>`

Comment: Pre-receive hook must read those from stdin (with a loop), update hook gets them as arguments.  But you're right, that's the order for a pre-receive hook.  (Irrelevant generic git complaint: why the difference in order? :-) )  See githooks(5) for more.

Comment: Ah, thx for pointing me at githooks(5). You're right. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Did a quick check in git source; it turns out it's also trivial to spoof committer name: put GIT_COMMITTER_NAME in environment.  (GIT_{AUTHOR,COMMITTER}_{NAME,EMAIL,DATE} are all taken from environment first if set.)  So this won't protect against malicious commits, but will prevent accidents.